# how do i keep my div's on the top margin

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my web design. I have a div `class="main-area"` containing 2 div's.

```
div class="half"
div class= "half second-half"
```

the `.half` contains text and the `.second-half` contains a picture. For images I have the following css:

```
img max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0 ;
```

but when i scale the browser down, the image scales with the browser but sticks in the vertical middle of the `main-area` div.

How can i make my `second-half` div stick to the top of the main div??

I tried margin-top `-xxxx px` and `- xxx%` but this does not work since the image scales so the main div scales.

here are images wich show what i mean, hope this helps because i dont know what jsfiddle is and how it works.

i got the link to the jsfiddle down below
http://jsfiddle.net/8zaSy/ 

i hope this is good enough?

Comment: Can you show us an example, such as in JSFiddle?

Comment: Did you tried to give vertical-align: top for the img?

Comment: Providing whole code where we can actually see what is wrong will move you closer to getting a good answer. (usually best to show it in http://jsfiddle.net as written above)

Comment: i found the problem, i was building the html again and had an id on the image wich had an margin-top of 180px. this caused the problems....  thanx alot for the help though guys :D

Comment: Happens :D btw I hope you aren't one of the http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.second-half img { max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
           float:left;
    marging-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/8zaSy/1/)

It seems you just want your image to be aligned top of the page. If this is the issue, then i have added it in the js fiddle above.

```
#indexpic {
    border: 1px dashed grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*margin-top: 180px;*/
}
```

If you have any other issue, then please comment, and modify the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/8zaSy/1/).

Regards D.

Comment: Else you can also also check this code, in which twitter bootstrap is also used to make it a responsive website. [JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/hL2sB/1/)